# Why is my Apple keep asking me to change my password for no reason? is it hacked?

Tags: password-management, ios

Just changed into a new password like three months ago, and it keep ask me to change into a new password, and the system is very stupid in denying that my new password is correct and constantly ask me to set up a new one after another new one. Is my iphone hacked?

Comment: It seems that someone is trying to reset your passwords; is there any notifications apple is sending about this?  Do you have 2FA enabled?

Comment: yes believe so, but it seems it's just my computer says that my new password is wrong and ask to set up a new one, and my phone send a 2fa code asking for permission of the computer to set up password, so on ....

Comment: Take it offline for a day or two (If you can afford to do that). See if it keeps happening. If it keeps happening, keep it offline and run a few different malware products, specifically ones that can look for fileless malware. I am not very up-to-date on OSX otherwise I would reccomend some software.

Comment: This is a valid question, and I've heard many people ask it. And when asking the question this is always about the amount of information they have available.

Answer (score 2):

This type of thing sounds to me like something somewhere has an old password stored someplace and is trying to use that password to log in resulting in the account being locked. This could be iTunes on a computer, iCloud or even your web browser or password manager if you are trying to log into an Apple related web service. It could even be some other iDevice like an iPad or iPod. If that is the case you'd have to locate what ever it is that isn't using your new password and make sure to change it there the next time you change your password.

Comment: And when someone says "why is Apple asking me" that doesn't mean it must be Apple; more likely some company account. I think Apple doesn't lock out people on their Apple accounts when the wrong password is used too often.

Comment: @gnasher729 It certainly is possible that it isn't Apple or an issue with their Apple account. Last time I had to change my password for work my iPhone seemed to have problems getting on board with using the new password and I had to unlock my windows account several times until I finally gave up and changed the password again. I would be surprised if Apple didn't do something for repeated failed login attempts given how security contentious they seem to be and how much effort has gone into the iPhone security and encryption but that doesn't mean they force a password change.

Comment: @gnasher729 I've had issues with apple locking me out for wrongly entering my security reset questions and such. Not sure if they extendded their policy to passwords.